# using example design of GTP

Tags: fpga

I programmed my Artix7 with GTP example design of Xilinx, in fact after setting the Wizard of GTP with my favorite parameters, i opened the Example Design and then create constraint file with respect to my board and generated the bitstream, and program my board. now i have a serous problem and, i have now idea how to use this Example for my work, and my work is simply send data from one board to another, my question is how should i prepare my data to send? and on the other board how should i prepare received data for my work? do not get me wrong i use wizard in the exact way user guide says. and write the constraint file based on my constraint file

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Using gtp transceiver to send and recive data

Comment: What protocol are you using? Transceivers are not easy to use and generated core by the wizards is more than buggy ... You should use a predefined protocol like Aurora.

Comment: in the wizard i chose **XAUI** protocol with 6Gbps. it's no problem i can chose Aurora, but where can i put my data to send? and in which parameter i can receive data? i know TXP and TXN send data in a differential manner and RXP and RXN, do the receive job, but i really do not know what should do and how i'm going to prepare that data to send

Comment: What kind of data?  Framed data?  Unframed data?  Half duplex?  Full duplex?  Word size?  Frame size?  Error detection?  Error correction?  Data rate?  Frame rate?  Burst or continuous?  etc, etc, etc.  Can't help unless we know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's full duplex and data has **ETHERNET** frame. And the word size.with error detection and data rate is 6 Gbps. Burst or continuous is not important. My cristal clock for gtp ref clock is 200 MHtz and FPGA clock is 100 MHtz, the FPGA is XC7A200T, my question is where i can put my data to send and from where i can receive thw income data